# No RTE is shown in TYPO3 BE using EXT:fluidcontent and flux:field.text

Tags: fedext

My fluidcontent content element shows no RTE Editor in the TYPO3 backend, only a simple textarea.

```
<flux:field.text label="Text" name="text" enableRichText="TRUE" defaultExtras="richtext[*]:rte_transform[mode=ts_css]"/>
```

I use TYPO3 v6.2.9 and all needed extensions as Git Version from [Github](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3).

How can I fix this?

Comment: I found the solution here [BUG: Rich Text Editor](https://github.com/bootstraptheme-for-typo3/fluidbootstraptheme/issues/63)

Check user settings => tab => Edit & Advanced functions => RTE option

Comment: You can have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940825/rich-text-editor-inside-flux-form/31941586#31941586

Answer (score 0):

See comment.

Please, `Enable Rich Text Editor (if available)`
USER TOOLS -> User Settings -> Edit & Advanced functions

[image]

Mark your question as solved. Thx.