# Rich Text Editor inside Flux Form

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, flux

I am using flux and I want to display rte(Rich text editor) in backend form using flux.

```
 <f:section name="Configuration"> 
    //...Here i want to display rte element
 </f:section>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Flux Form you can use Below code

```
<f:section name="Configuration">
   <flux:field.text name="Text" label="Whatever" enableRichText="1" />
</f:section>
```

In the Form You can use below

```
<f:section name="Main">
    <f:format.html>{Text}</f:format.html> 
<f:section name="Main">
```

**Please Enable Rich Text Editor From `Tools >> User Setting >> Edit & Advanced functions.`**

For More Help You can [see here](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/flux/master/Field/TextViewHelper.html)

Comment: Easier solution: `<flux:field.text name="Text" label="Whatever" enableRichText="1" />` - No `defaultExtras` needed.